# SwiftUI bug? Elements invisible in Voice Over mode

Tags: swift, accessibility, voiceover, zstack

I'm facing issues with the visibility of the elements inside `ZStack` in VoiceOver mode.
I'm building a View where I got navigation tabs inside `ScrollView` (green tabs on picture), and on top of that I want to have a sticky, non-scrollable tab (orange tab on picture).

[image]

Tabs are scrolling beneath the sticky fixed tab. The problem is, that in VoiceOver mode, `Sticky Tab` area is not recognisable, instead the element behind (in this case tab from the scroll view) gets snapped. Sticky tab is just invisible.

Evidence:

[image]

[image]

**Is this is some kind SwiftUI bug? I've tried everything.**
Any help appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var items = [
    Tab(icon: Image(systemName: "circle"), label: "tab1"),
    Tab(icon: Image(systemName: "circle"), label: "tab2"),
    Tab(icon: Image(systemName: "circle"), label: "tab3"),
    Tab(icon: Image(systemName: "circle"), label: "tab4"),
    Tab(icon: Image(systemName: "circle"), label: "tab5"),
    Tab(icon: Image(systemName: "circle"), label: "tab6"),
]
    
var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            stickyTab("StickyTab")
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 24) {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        Button {
                            print("Tapped!")
                        } label: {
                            HStack(spacing: 4) {
                                item.icon
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                Text(item.label)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                            }
                            .padding(.horizontal, 4)
                            .frame(height: 80)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            .background(Color.green)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.leading, 150)
            }
            .zIndex(0)
        }
        .background(Color.green.opacity(0.2))
}

@ViewBuilder
private func stickyTab(_ title: String) -> some View {
    Button {
        print("Tap!")
    } label: {
        HStack(spacing: 4) {
            Image(systemName: "circle")
            Text(title).foregroundColor(.black).font(.headline)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())

    }
    .frame(height: 80)
    .scaledToFit()
    .background(Color.orange)
    .accessibilityElement(children: .combine)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .zIndex(1)
}
```

}